# A way to conj 2 values onto a returned list?

Tags: recursion, clojure, artificial-intelligence

```
    (defn returnLoc [obj-data super-cat]
  ;If the list passed through is not empty
  (if-not (empty? obj-data)
    ;If the super-category passed in (i.e. Fruit/Agent) is equal
    ;to the Super-Category (the second object in the first row)
    (if (= super-cat (nth (first obj-data) 2))
      ;Recurvisely goes through the same process as above,
      ;To see if there is any other records in the list with the same super-cat
      ;then finds the location of the object and conj[oin]'s that to the returned values
      (conj (returnLoc (rest obj-data) super-cat)
            (nth (first obj-data) 3))
      ;If the super-cat passed through is not equal, it does not add it to the list
      ;And recursively goes back through to check if there are any other possible items to add to
      ;the list.
      (returnLoc (rest obj-data) super-cat)
      )
    ())
  )
```

As you can see I am returning the 3rd value of the obj-data once the code has found a match, is there a way where I can get the 2nd value of obj-data to return with the 3rd each time, and then add a separator on the end of that,

It currently returns a location of an item (fruit/agent) but I want it to return the specific item and location.

So it looks like:

```
(returnLoc obj-data 'agent)
```

returns:

```
=>(hallway bedroom)
```

where ideally I'd like it to return:

```
=>(tom is in hallway | jerry is in  bedroom)
```

Does anyone have a solution on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you make your solution more idiomatic, your immediate problems disappear:

1. Represent each element of `obj-data` as a map (or record), not as a list.
2. Recognise the pattern of the `returnLoc` computation.

**1. Represent each element of `obj-data` as a map (or record), not as a list.**

Your desired solution might then be

```
[{:who 'Tom, :where 'hallway} {:who 'Jerry, :where 'bedroom}]
```

This is quite readable, so you needn't hurry to translate it into flat text.

**2. Recognise the pattern of the `returnLoc` computation.**

What does `returnLoc` do?

- It selects the elements of obj-data that have a particular
  characeristic: their `:where` value is `super-cat`. This is a
  [`filter`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter) operation.
- It extracts the `:who` attribute from all such elements. This is a
  [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) operation.

Your `returnLoc` function might then be

```
(defn returnLoc [obj-data super-cat]
  (map
    :who
    (filter
      #(= (:where %) super-cat)
      obj-data)))
```

... or, using a threading macro,

```
(defn returnLoc [obj-data super-cat]
  (->> obj-data
       (filter #(= (:where %) super-cat))
       (map :who)))
```

- The keywords `:who` and `:where` are used as accessor functions.
- These versions maintain the order of the elements in `obj-data`. Your
  code reverses it.

---

Since you want to keep both the `:who` and `:where` fields, why not simply return the whole map/record:

```
(defn returnLoc [obj-data super-cat]
  (filter
    #(= (:where %) super-cat)
    obj-data))
```

This *saves* work, as the immutable map is returned by reference. No new map need be constructed.

If you are determined to get rid of the other fields, use `select-keys`:

```
(defn returnLoc [obj-data super-cat]
  (->> obj-data
       (filter #(= (:where %) super-cat))
       (map #(select-keys % [:who :where]))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`conj` takes more than one element to be added to the collection:

```
(conj '(on this list) 'elements 'two)
; ==> (two elements on this list)
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured out my own solution that works:

```
(def obj-data
              '((apple#3 apple fruit kitchen)
                 (mango#5 mango fruit kitchen)
                 (tom cat agent hallway)
                 (jerry mouse agent bedroom)
                 (matthew JavaStudentMatthew student livesAtHome)
                 (tom NetworkStudentTom student newcastleHome)
                 (Nathan NetworkStudentNathan student middlesbroughHome)
                 (Jack NetworkStudentJack student kexgillHome)
                 ))

(defn returnLoc [obj-data super-cat]
  ;If the list passed through is not empty
  (if-not (empty? obj-data)
    ;If the super-category passed in (i.e. Fruit/Agent) is equal
    ;to the Super-Category (the second object in the first row)
    (if (= super-cat (nth (first obj-data) 2))
      ;Recurvisely goes through the same process as above,
      ;To see if there is any other records in the list with the same super-cat
      ;then finds the location of the object and conj[oin]'s that to the returned values
      (cons (list (nth (first obj-data) 1) " is in " (nth (first obj-data) 3))
      (returnLoc (rest obj-data) super-cat))
      ;If the super-cat passed through is not equal, it does not add it to the list
      ;And recursively goes back through to check if there are any other possible items to add to
      ;the list.
      (returnLoc (rest obj-data) super-cat)
      )
    ())
  )
```